# The WiX Toolset v3.11 (or newer) build tools must be installed to build this project

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, wix, visual-studio-2017

Just installed Visual Studio 2017 and wix extension and when trying to build a solution which uses Wix I get the following error:

```
Error       The WiX Toolset v3.11 (or newer) build tools must be installed to build this project. Could not find wix.targets at 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\WiX\v3.x\'. To download WiX Toolset v3.11 (or newer), see http://wixtoolset.org/releases/ Installer   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\WiX\v3.x\Wix.targets 10
```

In folder "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\WiX\v3.x\" I have the following files

```
2017-11-29  15:12    <DIR>          .
2017-11-29  15:12    <DIR>          ..
2017-05-01  07:34           293 705 difxapp_x64.wixlib
2017-05-01  07:34           203 950 difxapp_x86.wixlib
2017-02-27  23:52             3 369 LICENSE.TXT
2017-02-27  23:52             4 233 lux.targets
2017-03-28  02:20             9 067 wix.ca.targets
2017-05-01  07:32             1 731 wix.nativeca.targets
2017-03-28  02:20             1 097 wix.targets
2017-02-27  23:52           145 601 wix200x.targets
2017-02-27  23:52           146 067 wix2010.targets
```

Which includes the file "wix.targets" which Visual Studio reports as missing. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A computer-restart later and its now working. So if someone have the same problem I recommend this after installing WiX. (restarting visual studio was not enough)

Comment: Sorry, but I have restarted Windows 10, I have started a REBUILD and I continue to have same error.

Comment: Thanks. I have desintalled and reinstalled Wix Toolset V3.11;1 AND VS Extension Wix Toolset Visual Studio Extension and in installing both, I have solved my problem. SHAME to Microsoft to have remove Setup from Visual Studio. Before (good time) I use Microsoft Setup. After (before) I install Wix and use it. Now, in 2018, I install Wix, I install Wix extension and use it. Where is the progress !!!

Comment: @schlebe it's a mess. One of the biggest companies in the world and the recommended way to create an installer is a (very well-maintained) open source project.

Answer (score 10):

To fix this issue you need download and install:
"**WiX Toolset build tools**" also,
NOT just
"**WiX Toolset Visual Studio Extension**"
from here: https://wixtoolset.org/releases/

Comment: it's here: 'https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/releases/tag/wix3112rtm' file: 'wix311.exe'

Answer (score 4):

Open your csprog project file with notepad and edit this line (in my case I use WiX version 4)

From:

```
<WixCATargetsPath Condition=" '$(WixCATargetsPath)' == '' ">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\WiX Toolset\v4\Wix.CA.targets</WixCATargetsPath>
```

To:

```
<WixCATargetsPath Condition=" '$(WixCATargetsPath)' == '' ">C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v4.0\SDK\Wix.CA.targets</WixCATargetsPath>
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried the above solution and wasn't able to resolve the issue even after repeated reinstall and reboots.

I removed the existing setup project and created a new setup project, this solved my issue. Caution, backup your setup project before removing it so you don't loose your work or have to recreate from scratch.

May be a tip to others who might be stuck with the issue even after reinstall and reboots.

Answer (score 1):

I had installed the WiX.Toolset package via NuGet package manager. Latest is 3.9.1208 as of this post, however my installer wanted at least 3.11. I uninstalled the WiX.Toolset package and installed the Wix.Toolset.UnofficialFork package, which is v3.11.2. After a restart of VS, everything worked great.

Answer (score 1):

**problem:** even though the tool set not present , it was shpwing already installed and not showing in the  controlled panel program list as well .

**Solution**
if you are getting the error "The WiX Toolset v3.11 (or newer) build tools must be installed to build this project" then need to nuget pkg manager and installed it manually , which will resolve this error . it worked for me .

Answer (score 0):

I to have problem in WiX Toolset I have reinstalled multiple times but the issue is not fixed. after I have tried with NuGet package manager I have installed 3.14  the issue is resolved