# Create msi of asp.net web api core 2.0 project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, wix, windows-services, windows-installer

I am creating a ASP.net core 2.0 WEB API project that is required to be deploy as a Windows service on a system using a MSI setup. Is there any way I can do it ?

Things that I have already tried:

1. I created an MSI using Setup Project but it doesn't load any dependencies.
2. I tried to create an msi using [WIX](https://nblumhardt.com/2017/04/netcore-msi/) but it shows error **The WiX Toolset v3.11 (or newer) build tools must be installed to build this project** I have tried solution which are already answered on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47555006/he-wix-toolset-v3-11-or-newer-build-tools-must-be-installed-to-build-this-proj) and  [this](https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/5564).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short on time, just some links to see if it gets you going:

- [**Various Deployment Tools**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50229840/129130) (quick rundown of deployment tools for MSI creation)
- [**WiX Quick Start Suggestions**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25004226/msi-vs-nuget-packages-which-are-is-better-for-continuous-delivery/25005864#25005864) (oddly enough this answer seems to help people)
- [A very quick overview of MSI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49624070/how-to-create-windows-installer/49632260#49632260) (also see the top links to [installsite.org's](http://installsite.org) rundown of setup tools)

Essentially:

1. You need to download and install the **WiX toolkit** to run WiX.
2. If you want to work with WiX source files in Visual Studio, you should also get the **Visual Studio Extension** (in addition to the main WiX download).
3. **Download both from here**: http://wixtoolset.org/releases/

I like to add the `bin` folder in the main WiX installation directory to the Path environment variable to be able to call WiX build tools - `candle.exe`, `light.exe`, `etc...` - from anywhere.

You can compile WiX source files outside Visual Studio as well. In its simplest form:

```dos
set SetupName=MySetup

candle.exe %SetupName%.wxs >> %SetupName%.log
light.exe -out %SetupName%.msi %SetupName%.wixobj >> %SetupName%.log
```

Or, without the line-noise:

```dos
candle.exe Setup.wxs
light.exe -out Setup.msi Setup.wixobj
```

---

Similar Questions:

- [Visual Studio 2017 C# installer project is not installing my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50607925/visual-studio-2017-c-sharp-installer-project-is-not-installing-my-app/50612524#50612524)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by creating an msi using Wix. I watched [this Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Yf-eDsRrnM) and followed its instruction.

- For creating windows service I used NSSM, I copied nssm.exe as a part of installer.
   used the following command:
    *nssm install service-name*
- For creating service automatically I used the CustomAction of WiX.

Answer (score 1):

To create an MSI for .Net core 2… first publish your project like

```
dotnet publish --configuration Release --runtime win7-x64 --self-contained false --output c:\outputfolder
```

You can make it part of your .wixproj by adding

```
 <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <BasePath>$(SolutionDir)\publish\bin\$(Configuration)\FilesToPackage</BasePath>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <!-- Clean previous build folder -->
    <Exec Command="rd /s /q $(BasePath)" />

    <!-- Publish dotnet core app -->
    <Exec Command="dotnet publish $(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)\..\..\src\yourproject.csproj -r win-x64 --self-contained false --output $(BasePath)" />

    <!-- Get assembly version -->
    <GetAssemblyIdentity AssemblyFiles="$(BasePath)\yourproject.dll">
      <Output TaskParameter="Assemblies" ItemName="AssemblyVersion" />
    </GetAssemblyIdentity>

    <!-- Define some variables we need -->
    <PropertyGroup>
      <DefineConstants>ProductVersion=%(AssemblyVersion.Version);BasePath=$(BasePath)</DefineConstants>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <HeatDirectory 
      OutputFile="YourServiceComponent.wxs" 
      DirectoryRefId="INSTALLFOLDER" 
      ComponentGroupName="yourproject_component"
      SuppressCom="true" Directory="$(BasePath)"
      SuppressFragments="true"
      SuppressRegistry="true"
      SuppressRootDirectory="true"
      AutoGenerateGuids="false"
      GenerateGuidsNow="true"
      ToolPath="$(WixToolPath)"
      PreprocessorVariable="var.BasePath"
      Transforms="RemoveFiles.xslt" 
      />
  </Target>
```

Heat will create the wxs file with all the files from the output but you need to remove yourservice.exe so add that information to RemoveFiles.xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:key name="pdb-search" match="wix:Component[contains(wix:File/@Source, '.pdb')]" use="@Id" />
  <xsl:template match="wix:Component[key('pdb-search', @Id)]" />
  <xsl:template match="wix:ComponentRef[key('pdb-search', @Id)]" />

  <xsl:key name="service-search" match="wix:Component[contains(wix:File/@Source, 'Your.Service.exe')]" use="@Id"/>
  <xsl:template match="wix:Component[key('service-search', @Id)]"/>
  <xsl:template match="wix:ComponentRef[key('service-search', @Id)]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Finally you want Wix to register your service with Windows Service Control Manager (SCM) so add the following to your Product.wxs

```
  <Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="yourproject_component" />

      <Component Id="ServiceAssemblyComponent" Guid="{GUID}">
        <File Id="ServiceAssembly" Source="$(var.BasePath)\Your.Service.exe" KeyPath="yes" />
        <ServiceInstall Id="ServiceInstallation" DisplayName="$(var.ProductName)" Name="$(var.ProductName)" ErrorControl="normal" Start="auto" Type="ownProcess"  Vital="yes" />
        <ServiceControl Id="ServiceControl" Name="$(var.ProductName)" Stop="both" Remove="uninstall" />
      </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>
  </Fragment>
```