# How to Create MSI installer using Command Line with WIX

Tags: .net, command-line, msbuild, wix, wix3.7

I have tried to use Wix and the following command :

```
candle 
light
```

here we need to create a .wxs file which I have already done but am unable to create MSI.

I have a doubt, I have my project which I have built it using MSBuild and now I need to create the MSI but I am unable to do it, how to provide my project binaries PATH  to Wix?

Comment: I suppose you could [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60757093/129130). There are also a few other answer you can skim: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58145510/129130), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58174058/129130).