# Problem building a Wix wxs file in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: configuration, wix

I just installed WiX on my machine and then installed the extension for Visual Studio 2017. When I attempt to build the Product.wxs I get "Could not find wix.targets at ''" back. I can run a build from the command line using candle and light, but I need to be able to do this with VS. Is there a place I can configure Visual Studio to look for the wix.targets file. I'm guessing that is the problem since it looking at '' for the file.

Comment: I use the wix nuget package these days.  Have you tried installing that?  The package is simply called WiX and the latest version is v3.11.1.

Comment: Did you reboot after installation? I would try that first of all. Just to be sure. There could have been Visual Studio locks going on during installation. [Similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47555006/the-wix-toolset-v3-11-or-newer-build-tools-must-be-installed-to-build-this-pro).

Comment: Did you install the right version of the Visual Studio 2017 extension btw?

Answer (score 1):

Create a WiX v3 project not v4.