# .NET CLI build doesn't work with Wix Project

Tags: .net, wix, wix3.11

My solution has 2 projects:

1. A .NET 6 project
2. A Wix Project to build an installer.

When I build the solution in Visual Studio, it works and my msi is generated. However when I try the same with the command:

```
 dotnet build 'foo.sln'
```

I get the following error:

> error
> : The WiX Toolset v3.11 (or newer) build tools must be installed to build this project. To download the WiX Toolset, se
> e http://wixtoolset.org/releases/

I tried setting the `WixTargetsPath` in my .wixproj to the absolute path of the Wix bin folder but still no luck. Any idea why is it so?

Comment: Looks like you also need WiX Toolset build tools, and this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47555006/the-wix-toolset-v3-11-or-newer-build-tools-must-be-installed-to-build-this-pro suggests you make sure to reboot after installing everything.

Comment: Restarting the machine does not solve it. I have it installed since I few weeks now. Also I am using the WixTool set and not the Visual Studio extension.

Answer (score 1):

WiX v3 doesn't support "core" MSBuild. Use "Framework" MSBuild instead. WiX v4 (coming to preview soon) is built on .NET 6 and `dotnet build` works.